# substitute letters with corresponding set of letters

Tags: regex, r

I stuck on a minor problem and I haven't found the right search terms for it.
I have letters from "A" - "N" and want to replace these one greater than "G"  with "A"-"G" according to their position in the alphabet. using `gsub` for that seems cumbersome. Or are there any regex that can do it smarter?

```
k <- rep(LETTERS[1:14],2)
gsub(pattern="H", replace="A", x=k)
gsub(pattern="I", replace="B", x=k)
gsub(pattern="J", replace="C", x=k)
gsub(pattern="K", replace="D", x=k)
# etc.
```

Isn't there some way I can convert the the characters to integer and then simply calculate within the integer values and afterwards casting back? Or is there any inverse of LETTERS?
`as.numeric()` and `as.integer()` returns `NA`.

Comment: As you've probably figured out from the suggested answers, `match` is the `as.numeric` you're looking for: `match(c("A","S","K"), LETTERS)` will return {1, 19, 11}.

Comment: Yep thanks. match() I need to remember. So many new things and I nearly always forget something I came across earlier. Although match is pretty new for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This translates H-N to A-G:

```
chartr("HIJKLMN", "ABCDEFG", k)
```

Comment: Nice. Hard to beat that in this case, I'd say.

Comment: Yet again, I put reading through the list of functions in `base` on my to do list.  Thanks for pointing this one out.

Comment: Uh, I came across that function when I was searching for a proper replace function. However I did not try it because I was assuming the old a new parameter was only applicable within one string not for vectors. I should have tried it. BTW anyone an idea what chartr stands for?  Its easier to remember it.

Answer (score 4):

My first thought whenever I see problems like this is `match`:

```
AG <- LETTERS[1:7]
HN <- LETTERS[8:14]

k <- rep(LETTERS[1:14],2)
n <- AG[match(k, HN)]
ifelse(is.na(n), k, n)
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
#[20] "F" "G" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G"
```

I'd construct an inverse `LETTERS` function the same way:

```
invLETTERS <- function(x) match(x, LETTERS[1:26])
invLETTERS(k)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#[26] 12 13 14
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a clean and straightforward solution:

```
k <- rep(LETTERS[1:14],2)

# (1) Create a lookup vector whose elements can be indexed into  
#     by their names and will return their associated values
subs <- setNames(rep(LETTERS[1:7], 2), LETTERS[1:14])
subs
#   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N 
# "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" 

# (2) Use it.
unname(subs[k])
#  [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G"
# [15] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there's a way to make this more compact, but this is probably the sort of thing you were thinking of in your second, non-regex idea:

```
k <- factor(k)
> k1 <- as.integer(k) %% 7
> k1[k1 == 0] <- 7
> LETTERS[k1]
 [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "A"
[23] "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G"
```

There's probably a clever way to sidestep the 0 index issue, but I'm not feeling terribly clever at the moment.

**Edit**

Good suggestions from the comments. First, to handle the 0 form the modular arithmetic:

```
k1 <- ((as.integer(k)-1) %%7) + 1
```

and combined with `match` it turns into a one-liner:

```
k1 <- LETTERS[((match(k, LETTERS)-1) %% 7) + 1]
```

Comment: Here, you can borrow some cleverness, and pay it back later ;) `k1 <- ((as.integer(k)-1) %%7) + 1`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I like the cleverness. It makes it so this can be solved in one line: `k1 = LETTERS[((match(k, LETTERS)-1) %% 7) + 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is only with A-N:

```
set.seed(1)
k = sample(LETTERS[1:14], 42, replace=TRUE)
temp = match(k, LETTERS)
# > table(k)
# k
# A B C D E F G I J K L M N 
# 2 2 5 2 1 6 3 3 5 4 3 3 3 
k[which(temp > 7)] = LETTERS[temp[temp > 7] -7]
# > table(k)
# k
# A  B  C  D  E  F  G 
# 2  5 10  6  4  9  6
```